# mpm-prefork-module config doesn't seem to apply

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu

I'm running Ubuntu 12.10 and Apache 2.4.6.

I've got

```
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
    StartServers        20
    MinSpareServers     20
    MaxSpareServers     30
    MaxClients          256
    MaxRequestsPerChild 1000
</IfModule>
```

In my apache2.conf file, but it doesn't seem to do anything, as even under heavy stress testing, the server only spawns up to 10 apache processes.

Any advice?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you grep in your Apache config directory for any other files (like in `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled`) that are also setting these directives?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response.

The mods-enabled directory contains a mpm_prefork.conf and mpm_prefork.load files which are links to the same files in mods-available directory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/mpm_prefork.conf` file's configuration of these directives is almost certainly overriding this configuration in your `apache2.conf`, due to the `Include` happening later in the `apache2.conf` than those directives are configured.

Change them in `mpm_prefork.conf` for your changes to take effect.

Comment: You're right, I didn't pay enough attention to the mods-enabled/*.conf directive! :)

It's now spawning many more children and making use of far more of the resources available.

I'd like to switch to mpm-worker, from prefork, but that's for another question I think. :) Thanks for the help.